# Why do I get "Destination Host Unreachable" on the same subnet, pinging a secondary IP address?

Tags: linux, networking, ping, arp

I have two AWS EC2 instances (RedHat 8), `sa216p` and `sa216t`, connected to the same subnet 172.31.80.0/20. Primary IP addresses are assigned to them by the EC2 DHCP, 172.31.84.105 and 172.31.92.210 respectively. On `sa216p` I assign a secondary address to the only interface, using `ip addr add 172.31.92.123/20 dev eth0`.

```
[ec2-user@sa216p ~]$ ip addr show dev eth0
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9001 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 12:a5:24:f4:78:05 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.31.84.105/20 brd 172.31.95.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft 3249sec preferred_lft 3249sec
    inet 172.31.92.123/20 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::10a5:24ff:fef4:7805/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

The security group for the VPC allows SSH and ICMP traffic on the subnet. There's no firewall installed on either instance, so far as I can see. The AWS route table contains an entry for `172.31.0.0/16 local`, covering the subnet in question.

From `sa216t` I can ping `sa216p` using both its host name and the IP address:

```
[ec2-user@sa216t ~]$ ping sa216p
PING sa216p (172.31.84.105) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from sa216p (172.31.84.105): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.584 ms
64 bytes from sa216p (172.31.84.105): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.674 ms
64 bytes from sa216p (172.31.84.105): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.540 ms
```

However, pinging the secondary address fails anyway:

```
[ec2-user@sa216t ~]$ ping 172.31.92.123
PING 172.31.92.123 (172.31.92.123) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 172.31.92.210 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 172.31.92.210 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 172.31.92.210 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
```

Neighbours table shows the address resolution was unsuccessful:

```
[ec2-user@sa216t ~]$ ip neigh
172.31.80.1 dev eth0 lladdr 12:c7:16:59:97:6f REACHABLE
172.31.91.6 dev eth0 lladdr 12:68:fb:11:f5:61 STALE
172.31.84.105 dev eth0 lladdr 12:a5:24:f4:78:05 REACHABLE
172.31.92.123 dev eth0  FAILED
```

On `sa216p` I can ping both IP addresses:

```
[ec2-user@sa216p ~]$ ping 172.31.84.105
PING 172.31.84.105 (172.31.84.105) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.31.84.105: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.021 ms
64 bytes from 172.31.84.105: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.035 ms
64 bytes from 172.31.84.105: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.031 ms
64 bytes from 172.31.84.105: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.020 ms
^C
--- 172.31.84.105 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3091ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.020/0.026/0.035/0.009 ms
[ec2-user@sa216p ~]$ ping 172.31.92.123
PING 172.31.92.123 (172.31.92.123) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.31.92.123: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.021 ms
64 bytes from 172.31.92.123: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.043 ms
64 bytes from 172.31.92.123: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.033 ms
64 bytes from 172.31.92.123: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.035 ms
^C
--- 172.31.92.123 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3071ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.021/0.033/0.043/0.007 ms
```

though address resolution apparently fails:

```
[ec2-user@sa216p ~]$ ip neigh
172.31.92.123 dev eth0  FAILED
172.31.95.166 dev eth0 lladdr 12:e5:55:02:1c:8f REACHABLE
172.31.80.1 dev eth0 lladdr 12:c7:16:59:97:6f REACHABLE
172.31.92.210 dev eth0 lladdr 12:9e:db:f8:9b:7f STALE
172.31.91.6 dev eth0 lladdr 12:68:fb:11:f5:61 REACHABLE
```

What am I missing? Why can't I reach `sa216p` on the secondary IP address?

P.S. There's a [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/1706491/why-does-ping-return-destination-host-unreachable-to-the-same-subnet), but in my case the target host is clearly alive and connected.

P.P.S. This might be specific to the AWS, because *I'm told* the same setup works as expected when run on-premises, using virtual machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it *is* indeed specific to AWS: one can only assign secondary private IP addresses using the AWS tooling, either from the management console or using the CLI, as [described in the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-eni.html#managing-network-interface-ip-addresses).